# kubectl: List pods whose names starting with a keyword string

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Using `kubectl`, how can I get a list of the pods whose name starts with a particular string?

#### Example

My pods:

```bash
$ kubectl get pods -n kong
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS         AGE
kong          foobar-cc7654c7b-htvmx             1/1     Running   0                19m
kong          kong-controller-549fcc4d84-s7l7b   1/1     Running   0                20m
kong          kong-gateway-699c995d4d-mf64r      1/1     Running   0                19m
```

I'd like to retrieve all the pods starting with "kong-":

```bash
$ kubectl get pods -n kong --no-headers <some_kind_of_selector>
kong          kong-controller-549fcc4d84-s7l7b   1/1     Running   0                20m
kong          kong-gateway-699c995d4d-mf64r      1/1     Running   0                19m
```

##### Pods labels

```json
// kong-controller-549fcc4d84-s7l7b
{
  "app": "kong-controller",
  "app.kubernetes.io/component": "app",
  "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "kong",
  "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm",
  "app.kubernetes.io/name": "controller",
  "app.kubernetes.io/version": "3.4",
  "helm.sh/chart": "controller-2.31.0",
  "pod-template-hash": "549fcc4d84",
  "version": "3.4"
}

// kong-gateway-699c995d4d-mf64r
{
  "app": "kong-gateway",
  "app.kubernetes.io/component": "app",
  "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "kong",
  "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Helm",
  "app.kubernetes.io/name": "gateway",
  "app.kubernetes.io/version": "3.4",
  "helm.sh/chart": "gateway-2.31.0",
  "pod-template-hash": "699c995d4d",
  "version": "3.4"
}
```

Comment: Do the specific pods have a common label you could use with `kubectl get -l`?  Or is `grep kong-` enough for your needs?

Comment: @DavidMaze `kong-controller-549fcc4d84-s7l7b` has a label "app":"kong-controller", while `kong-gateway-699c995d4d-mf64r` has a label "app":"kong-gateway", I can put the full list of the labels in the question if it can be useful

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kubectl` command as of now doesn’t support any type of **regex filters**.

Many requests were raised for including this feature in the kubernetes source code but were rejected, I’m including those **feature requests** for your references below. So, as of now the only possible solution is to use either **grep** or **awk** along with kubectl commands for filtering out resources starting with a particular string.

**References:**

1. [Propose LabelSelector to support Regexp operato](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/109400)r
2. [Allow wildcards in field selectors](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107053)
3. [Allow case-insensitive matching in selectors](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107285)

Comment: Thanks, I actually forgot to accept the answer, but that's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

can you use the grep command? For example:

```
kubectl get pods | grep -i 'kong'
```

Comment: This would indeed return the output of the example. But I was thinking of something directly using kubectl command and its options/selectors - even though I didn't exactly specify it in the question, my bad

Comment: That's ok! If you found it helpful I would like you to mark it as an answer :)

Comment: That's the point of my previous comment: I'm not updating the question to be more focused because I'm not sure if that'll invalidate your answer, but what I'd consider *the* answer is something that exploits directly `kubectl` command (my purpose is to also use other options like `-o jsonpath`)

Comment: Can you try this?
`kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}' | awk '/^specific-name-prefix/'`
If it'll work, I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: `kubectl get --no-headers pods -o name | awk -F"/" '$2 ~ /^kong-.*/'"`